# Tabulator - Download and re-use changes

Tags: tabulator

I am new to Tabulator and started building my first project. While usage and setup is very intuitive and nicely built I struggle with one concept. I want to keep changes and entries I made to the table and load them again when re-opening the page. 
My first thought was to download all entries as csv or xls and then import either from an array/JSON or from an HTML table. Is this the preferred way or is there another method I can use?

Thanks!

Note: I am using version 4.1

Answer (score 0):

Tabulator doesn't include what you are looking for.  However, you can use Tabulator to retrieve the table's values.  As for saving and restoring the edited data, you may want to use your browser's `localStorage`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage